# Amazon S3 AWS starts giving error code 400 for unknown reason

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am not sure since when, but on my development machine I get the following error using the AWS SDK with Java:

```
2015-02-24 18:57:05,834 DEBUG ~ Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
2015-02-24 18:57:05,834 DEBUG ~ << HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
2015-02-24 18:57:05,834 DEBUG ~ << Server: nginx
2015-02-24 18:57:05,834 DEBUG ~ << Date: Tue, 24 Feb 2015 18:57:05 GMT
2015-02-24 18:57:05,834 DEBUG ~ << Content-Type: application/xml
2015-02-24 18:57:05,834 DEBUG ~ << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2015-02-24 18:57:05,834 DEBUG ~ << Connection: keep-alive
2015-02-24 18:57:05,834 DEBUG ~ << Bucket: "testmedia"
2015-02-24 18:57:05,834 DEBUG ~ << Accept-Ranges: bytes
2015-02-24 18:57:05,834 DEBUG ~ << Age: 0
2015-02-24 18:57:05,834 DEBUG ~ << X-Cache-Hit: No
2015-02-24 18:57:05,835 DEBUG ~ Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2015-02-24 18:57:05,835 DEBUG ~  << "51[\r][\n]"
2015-02-24 18:57:05,835 DEBUG ~  << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code></Error>"
2015-02-24 18:57:05,835 DEBUG ~  << "[\r][\n]"
2015-02-24 18:57:05,835 DEBUG ~  << "0[\r][\n]"
2015-02-24 18:57:05,835 DEBUG ~  << "[\r][\n]"
2015-02-24 18:57:05,835 DEBUG ~ Connection [id: 8][route: {s}->https://testmedia.xxx] can be kept alive indefinitely
2015-02-24 18:57:05,835 DEBUG ~ Connection released: [id: 8][route: {s}->https://testmedia.xxx][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
2015-02-24 18:57:05,836 DEBUG ~ Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: null (Service: null; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
```

I can upload the file, so the credentials seem ok, but I don't seem to download it. I am using the Play! Framework (1.2.7) running JDK 1.7 and the AWS SDK 1.9.22.

What could be the cause of this?

It is recently that I did switch from JDK 1.6 to 1.7 because of a signing issue on 1.6 with AWS. I don't have it (yet) on my production servers, so it might be OS X related, but don't dare to deploy my code to production until I know for sure it will not break.

(aws-sdk-java/1.9.22 Mac_OS_X/10.10.3 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/24.71-b01/1.7.0_71)

[EDIT:]
My Java code:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfig.setConnectionTimeout(2500);

AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, clientConfig);
conn.setEndpoint(hostUrl);    
S3Object object = conn.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, fileKey));
```

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact the my S3 service seems to run CloudStack and the newest SDK does not work with it. With 1.8.11 it all works fine again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had to do with CloudStack and the SDK version. I downgraded to 1.8.11 and it all works fine again!

Comment: Interesting. downgraded to 1.8.11 also solve my a same problem. Although i m not using CloudStack.

Answer (score 1):

degrade to 1.8.x or use a s3signer like:

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfig.setSignerOverride("S3SignerType");
```

see here:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/issues/155